# 'UITableView' does not have a member in dequeneResusableCell

Tags: swift, xcode

I can't figure out how to solve this. It keeps throwing an error with the dequeneResuableCell. I've tried every variable available. I have xcode 6. I removed the outlets, because they are not the problem and I have not included the constructor/iniitalization for the HospitalList class.

This is the code

```
import UIKit

class HospitalList: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var hospitals: UITableView!

    var Hos: [Hospital] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Hos = createArray()
        hospitals.delegate = self
        hospitals.dataSource = self
    }

    func createArray() -> [Hospital] {
        \\more code to create an array of Information
        return tempHospitals

    }


}

extension HospitalList: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    //counts number of elements in Table View
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Hos.count
    }

    //sets up whats in the table view
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Hop = Hos[indexPath.row]
       // this line is the problem right here
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoHospitals")
        cell.HName.text = Hop.name \\and more, but not including

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell
}
```

Comment: Where did you register the tableView dequeable cells?

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I appreciate it. Sorry, I'm new to xcode and swift, like really new (been learning this for three days). Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Xcode 6? Really? That's quite a few years out of date which means the version of Swift you are using is seriously out of date. Actually, was Swift even available in Xcode 6? Please update to Xcode 10 and Swift 4 and update your code. It will make your life so much easier. Using such old tools is largely a waste of your time. Too much has changed since then.

Comment: I tried to update to xcode 10, but my old mac, an OS X Yosemite version 10.10, did not let me. I'm not a developer, but a stay-at-home mom, so don't really have the money to buy a new one with the 16 gig of this one. Is there a way to update this mac to xcode 10 without buying an new one?

Comment: Xcode 10 requires macOS 10.13.4 or later. So it depends on how old your Mac is.

Comment: you need to implement number of row in section